# How to clip a Shape(Circle) with another Shape(Arc) in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, automatic-ref-counting, geometry, shapes, gauge

I am having a hard time trying to clip a circle with a arc. I am trying to reproduce this Thermostat

[image: Thermostat]

from this [video (starting at 43:45)](https://youtu.be/7is1WTtbZj4?t=43m45s) where the developer said that he used `Region`s, `Circle`s and an `Arc` for animation. So I can't see how to clip the circle with the animated arc.

My code so far...

```
//stroke is the circle without fill
    stroke.setClip(arc);
```

And I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Node's clip set to incorrect value (node already connected, node  = Circle[id=stroke, centerX=0.0, centerY=0.0, radius=200.0, fill=0x1f93ff00, stroke=0x63ff26ff, strokeWidth=30.0], clip = ObjectProperty [bean: Circle[id=stroke, centerX=0.0, centerY=0.0, radius=200.0, fill=0x1f93ff00, stroke=0x63ff26ff, strokeWidth=30.0], name: clip, value: null]).
```

So how can solve this issue?! I'm a huge fan of gauges and thermostat apps.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Could you edit the link to the video to point to the appropriate time? This video is >1h long and certainly I won't watch the whole video just to get an idea of the desired behaviour and I doubt many others would...

Comment: @fabia Sorry, [this](https://youtu.be/7is1WTtbZj4?t=2623) is the position. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to achieve the desired result: By simply using an [`Arc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Arc.html) without `fill` and with a the appropriate `strokeWidth`.

Example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    DoubleProperty value = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    DoubleProperty minValue = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    DoubleProperty maxValue = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    final double startOffset = 10;
    final double maxRange = 360 - 2 * startOffset;

    Arc arc = new Arc();
    arc.setFill(null);

    arc.setRadiusX(100);
    arc.setRadiusY(100);

    arc.setCenterX(110);
    arc.setCenterY(110);

    arc.setStrokeWidth(10);
    arc.setStroke(Color.WHITE.deriveColor(0, 0, 1, 0.5));
    arc.setStartAngle(270 - startOffset);
    arc.lengthProperty().bind(value.subtract(minValue).divide(maxValue.subtract(minValue)).multiply(-maxRange));

    Pane thermostatPane = new Pane();
    thermostatPane.setMinSize(220, 220);
    thermostatPane.getChildren().add(arc);
    thermostatPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange");

    Slider minSlider = new Slider(0, 100, 0);
    Slider maxSlider = new Slider(0, 100, 100);
    Slider valueSlider = new Slider(0, 100, 20);

    valueSlider.setPrefWidth(200);
    maxSlider.setPrefWidth(200);
    minSlider.setPrefWidth(200);

    value.bind(valueSlider.valueProperty());
    minValue.bind(minSlider.valueProperty());
    maxValue.bind(maxSlider.valueProperty());

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(10, thermostatPane, minSlider, valueSlider, maxSlider));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: i runned your code and this is what i got: #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x000007fee7115c01, pid=8484, tid=4996
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_65-b17) (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.65-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcr120.dll+0x95c01]
#

Comment: @Hayden Tested it using java 8u92 (working). This seems to be related to this bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8136754?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:worklog-tabpanel (at least that one also mentions a problematic frame and msvcr120.dll). Unfortunately I cannot help you with that issue. It should work with a java version not containing this bug, so you may get it to work using a different java runtime...